# Consuming a Web Service written in VS2008

Tags: web-services

I've got a Web Service written using C# in Visual Studio 2008 (I've also written it in VS 2005).
I can write a test windows form app to consume the service no problem.

The problem I have is consuming it from C#/VS2003 (or php which is my real problem). It just gives me the error:

**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestIntel.WebIntel.GetSitesResponseGetSitesResult' to 'System.Data.DataTable"**

The Web mthod does return a DataTable; as I said this works fine if the consumer was built in VS2005/2008.  What gives?

Comment: What type of web service is it? ASMX? WCF?

Comment: It's ASMX, I think my problem is what Chris Lively has answered. I just need to test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to consume a DataTable, the calling points (php and .net 1.1) need to know how to deserialize it into usable object.

This means that they would have to have a similiar object that the data can be deserialized into.

Obviously, PHP can't do that.  And the reason for the .net 1.1 error is that the DataTable object changed quite a bit between 1.1 and 2.0.  In fact, Microsoft says that the .Net 1.1 datatable object is BY DESIGN not supposed to be serialized through a web service. ( [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306134][1] )

If you are looking for a real cross language way of doing this then you need to serialize your response into a standard XML object.  Which could be parsed correctly by any language.  This is a little more work, but results in a usable service.

Comment: Just as you said, sorted It - Thanks.